# Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Error returned by javac

Tags: bash, hadoop, jdbc, sqoop

I am trying to run a simple sqoop import program using JAVA.

My Program:

```
    String driver="com.vertica.Driver";
    Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
    config.addResource(new Path("/../../../mapred-site.xml"));
    config.addResource(new Path("/../../../core-site.xml"));
    config.addResource(new Path("/../../../hdfs-site.xml"));

    SqoopOptions options = new SqoopOptions();
    options.setConnectString(connection_string);
    options.setDriverClassName(driver);

    options.setUsername(username);
    options.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    options.setTargetDir(directory path);
    options.setFetchSize(0);
    options.setSqlQuery("SELECT 123456 as runid, " +
            "business_date " +
            "FROM database.table " +
            "WHERE business_date=\'20140922\' " +
            "AND instrument_id=1037894110378941 " +
            "AND $CONDITIONS");

    int ret = new ImportTool().run(options);
    System.out.println("Return Val: "+ret);
```

I have the following error

```
15/02/03 02:26:23 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
15/02/03 02:26:23 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via  --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be     used next time.
15/02/03 02:26:23 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
15/02/03 02:26:24 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT 123456 as runid, business_date FROM silverscreen_qa.SS_INSTRUMENT WHERE  business_date='20140922' AND instrument_id=1037894110378941 AND  (1 = 0)
15/02/03 02:26:24 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT 123456 as runid, business_date FROM silverscreen_qa.SS_INSTRUMENT WHERE  business_date='20140922' AND instrument_id=1037894110378941 AND  (1 = 0)
15/02/03 02:26:24 INFO orm.CompilationManager: $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is not set
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:11: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge;
                             ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:12: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.DelimiterSet;
                             ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:13: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.FieldFormatter;
                             ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:14: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.RecordParser;
                             ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:15: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.BooleanParser;
                             ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:16: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.BlobRef;
                             ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:17: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.ClobRef;
                             ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:18: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.LargeObjectLoader;
                             ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:19: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.SqoopRecord;
                             ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
public class QueryResult extends SqoopRecord  implements DBWritable, Writable {
                                 ^
  symbol: class SqoopRecord
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
  public void loadLargeObjects(LargeObjectLoader __loader)
                               ^
  symbol:   class LargeObjectLoader
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
  private final DelimiterSet __outputDelimiters = new DelimiterSet((char) 44, (char) 10, (char) 0, (char) 0, false);
                ^   
  symbol:   class DelimiterSet  
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
  public String toString(DelimiterSet delimiters) {
                         ^
  symbol:   class DelimiterSet
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:129: error: cannot find symbol
  public String toString(DelimiterSet delimiters, boolean useRecordDelim) {
                         ^
  symbol:   class DelimiterSet
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:140: error: cannot find symbol
  private final DelimiterSet __inputDelimiters = new DelimiterSet((char) 44, (char) 10, (char) 0, (char) 0, false);
                ^
  symbol:   class DelimiterSet
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:141: error: cannot find symbol
  private RecordParser __parser;
          ^
  symbol:   class RecordParser
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:142: error: package RecordParser does not exist
  public void parse(Text __record) throws RecordParser.ParseError {
                                                      ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:150: error: package RecordParser does not exist
  public void parse(CharSequence __record) throws RecordParser.ParseError {
                                                              ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:158: error: package RecordParser does not exist
  public void parse(byte [] __record) throws RecordParser.ParseError {
                                                         ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:166: error: package RecordParser does not exist
  public void parse(char [] __record) throws RecordParser.ParseError {
                                                         ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:174: error: package RecordParser does not exist
  public void parse(ByteBuffer __record) throws RecordParser.ParseError {
                                                            ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:182: error: package RecordParser does not exist
  public void parse(CharBuffer __record) throws RecordParser.ParseError {
                                                            ^
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:64: error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
    if (this == o) {
             ^
  first type:  QueryResult
  second type: Object
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:67: error: inconvertible types
    if (!(o instanceof QueryResult)) {
          ^
  required: QueryResult
  found:    Object
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:70: error: inconvertible types
    QueryResult that = (QueryResult) o;
                                     ^
  required: QueryResult
  found:    Object
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
    this.runid = JdbcWritableBridge.readLong(1, __dbResults);
                 ^
  symbol:   variable JdbcWritableBridge
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
    this.business_date = JdbcWritableBridge.readDate(2, __dbResults);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable JdbcWritableBridge
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:89: error: cannot find symbol
    JdbcWritableBridge.writeLong(runid, 1 + __off, -5, __dbStmt);
    ^
  symbol:   variable JdbcWritableBridge
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
    JdbcWritableBridge.writeDate(business_date, 2 + __off, 91, __dbStmt);
    ^
  symbol:   variable JdbcWritableBridge
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
  private final DelimiterSet __outputDelimiters = new DelimiterSet((char) 44, (char) 10, (char) 0, (char) 0, false);
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class DelimiterSet
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:132: error: cannot find symbol
    __sb.append(FieldFormatter.escapeAndEnclose(runid==null?"null":"" + runid, delimiters));
                ^
  symbol:   variable FieldFormatter
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:134: error: cannot find symbol
    __sb.append(FieldFormatter.escapeAndEnclose(business_date==null?"null":"" + business_date, delimiters));
                ^
  symbol:   variable FieldFormatter
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:140: error: cannot find symbol
  private final DelimiterSet __inputDelimiters = new DelimiterSet((char) 44, (char) 10, (char) 0, (char) 0, false);
                                                     ^
  symbol:   class DelimiterSet
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:144: error: cannot find symbol
      this.__parser = new RecordParser(__inputDelimiters);
                          ^
  symbol:   class RecordParser
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:152: error: cannot find symbol
      this.__parser = new RecordParser(__inputDelimiters);
                          ^
  symbol:   class RecordParser
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:160: error: cannot find symbol
      this.__parser = new RecordParser(__inputDelimiters);
                          ^
  symbol:   class RecordParser
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:168: error: cannot find symbol
      this.__parser = new RecordParser(__inputDelimiters);
                          ^
  symbol:   class RecordParser
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:176: error: cannot find symbol
      this.__parser = new RecordParser(__inputDelimiters);
                          ^
  symbol:   class RecordParser
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:184: error: cannot find symbol
      this.__parser = new RecordParser(__inputDelimiters);
                          ^
  symbol:   class RecordParser
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:206: error: cannot find symbol
    QueryResult o = (QueryResult) super.clone();
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class QueryResult
/tmp/sqoop-sha0_dev/compile/bda7671a1a4e5e172248f2497654d2c1/QueryResult.java:208: error: incompatible types
    return o;
           ^
  required: Object
  found:    QueryResult
41 errors
15/02/03 02:26:24 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Error returned by javac
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.compile(CompilationManager.java:207)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:97)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:396)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:502)
        at com.cts.rbc.archive.TestConnectionForHive.main(TestConnectionForHive.java:196)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

Return Val: 1
```

Possible Solutions I tried.

In my hadoop-env.sh the value of JAVA_HOME is

```
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.65.x86_64
```

I know this sounds repeated but believe me I have tried all solutions described in the solutions provided in similar questions

I tried changing JAVA_HOME in ~/.bashrc with the below code

```
    JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java
```

This is where latest java is installed in my node
It still throws the same error.

The same query works in bash.

Note: I don't have permission to alter JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh as its a shared system.

Possible way to overwrite JAVA_HOME in Java Program?

Comment: I export the code to jar and run it in my unix. The error is from putty and not eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solved]

There was no need to change java_home (or) hadoop_mapred_home (or) sqoop_home

As the error suggests, it was not able to find sqoop library. Whereas I used sqoop 1.4.4 library in my program. 
Please note that I wasn't using any build tool (Maven, SBT or anything)
I was using normal eclipse and adding external .jar to my program.

While exporting the .jar I was using Eclipse standard method (File -> Export -> Java -> Runnable .jar File)

In launch configuration I selected my appropriate project
and in library handling, I was using the option "package required libraries into generated JAR"

When I selected "extract required libraries into generated JAR" and executed .jar file it was executed successfully.